Realizar una publicación en una página de facebook y grupos
Estoy realizando un código que realice una publicación cada determinado tiempo en una página de Facebook y posteriormente, se comparta esa publicación en un grupo, realice una app desde modo desarrollador de Facebook y le otorgue los permisos necesarios para que publique en la página, sin embargo ya no permite agregar los permisos para publicar/compartir en los grupos
Este es el código
import requests
    import schedule
    import time
    
    # Configura tus credenciales y detalles de publicación
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = '**************' # Reemplaza con tu token de acceso
PAGE_ID = '**************'  # Reemplaza con el ID de tu página
GROUP_ID = '**************'  # Reemplaza con el ID del grupo
MESSAGE = 'Prueba'
INTERVAL_MINUTES = x  # Intervalo en minutos

def post_to_facebook():
    # Publicar el mensaje en la página
    post_url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed'
    post_payload = {
        'access_token': PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        'message': MESSAGE
    }
    
    response = requests.post(post_url, data=post_payload)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Publicación realizada exitosamente.')
        post_id = response.json().get('id')
        print(f'ID de la publicación: {post_id}')

    else:
        print('Error al realizar la publicación:')
        try:
            error_response = response.json()
            print(error_response)
            if 'error' in error_response:
                error_message = error_response['error']['message']
                error_code = error_response['error']['code']
                print(f"Error {error_code}: {error_message}")
                print("Detalles adicionales:", response.text)
        except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
            print("No se pudo decodificar la respuesta JSON")
            print("Contenido de la respuesta:", response.text)

def get_group_info(group_id, access_token):
    url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}'
    params = {'access_token': access_token}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Información del grupo:', response.json())
    else:
        print('Error al obtener información del grupo:')
        print(response.json())

# Obtener información del grupo
get_group_info(GROUP_ID, PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Publicar inmediatamente al iniciar el script
post_to_facebook()

# Programar la publicación cada x minutos
schedule.every(INTERVAL_MINUTES).minutes.do(post_to_facebook)

print(f"Programado para publicar cada {INTERVAL_MINUTES} minutos.")

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

Este error es el que me marca
Error al obtener información del grupo:
{'error': {'message': "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1552100522009825' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 33, 'fbtrace_id': 'AUwWgf2f0Fg_QLZ5EPjS3My'}}
Publicación realizada exitosamente.
ID de la publicación: 368207349714719_122106015764380890
Programado para publicar cada x minutos.

Espero puedan ayudarme
